# Cannot read property 'http' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Hi there i need to send transaction date to server after that ngx-paypal payment is exacuted. But i got this error: 
`Cannot read property 'http' of undefined`

here is my code:

```
 payPalConfig = {
  env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
                sandbox:    '########################',
                production: '#######################'
            },
    commit: true,

            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {
              // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                let prezzo = cookieService.get('importo');
                return actions.payment.create({
              payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
              amount: { total: prezzo, currency: 'EUR' }
                            }
                        ]

            }
                })
            },
    // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {
                  this.http.post('https://dev.miosit.it/aggiorna-abbonamento', response).subscribe(data=> {});

                });
            }
    };
```

How i can got http working in this case?

Comment: Use arrow functions maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the scope the **this** is used in. Try using arrow functions, it is usually more recommended. Your code will look like this.

```
return actions.payment.execute().then( (response) => { ...} );
```

Comment: now it's something else. Did you make sure to import the HttpClientModule properly in your module? And how does this class' constructor look like?

Comment: if i use public http: Http, instead of private http: Http working as well